# Decoding json escape sequences

Tags: json

Having created a text file with a JSON object (from an array) using json_encode, I'm now supposed to decode the same object. However, with json_decode, the unicode escape sequences don't seem to be properly converted back.

Here is the example of a string from the JSON file:

S\u00720066006f006cd industriomr\u00640065

After json_decoding, the text becomes:

Sr0066006f006cd industriomrd0065

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: It might help if you told us what language, framework etc. you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

The decoding seems to work fine; the final text does indeed correspond with the encoded one.  What was the object like before encoding?

Comment: Before encoding the text was "Sørfold industriområde".

Comment: And how did you encode it?  Because that's where it borked.  It should have encoded it to `"S\u00F8rfold industriomr\u00E5de"`.

Comment: I used the PHP function json_encode. However, I think I've discovered the problem. The original text was iso-8859-1, and from what I've read afterwards, JSON does not support this charset.